# log4j vulnerability - Sleuth dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

We heard that `log4j-core.jar` is vulnerable. 
We noticed that `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` (version 2.2.2.RELEASE) dependency brings a dependency which uses `log4j-core.jar` (version 2.13.0) with `provided` scope as followed:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The exact jar that brings the log4j dependency is:

```
<groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
<artifactId>brave-context-log4j2</artifactId>
<version>5.10.1</version>
```

We are not using Zipkin in our code or configurations, just Sleuth.
Is our code vulnerable?

Comment: No, it is a provided dependency means it doesn't take that version. So unless you are actually including that version (or anything other than 2.15) you are vulnerable.

Comment: @M.Deinum - If It's not provided, will it fail in runtime?

Comment: No. If it works now it works then. A `provided` dependency isn't part of the deployment (only compile and runtime). So again if this isn't in your deployable (your jar or war) it isn't an issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum So what if I'm using spring logback with sleuth that has vulnerable log4j in provided scope, does it mean I have nothing to be scared of?

Comment: No as that is only the API not log4j-core which has the vulnerabiltiy. Which is also explained in detail here https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

Answer (score -1):

Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.x is not supported anymore and as M. Deinum mentioned Sleuth will not bring these dependencies for you because of the `provided` scope. You can test this by running `gradlew dependencies` or `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: As far as I understand I will not see Provided in the `mvn dependency:tree` as it will be provided by the environment/OS/JVM and not getting packed. it's also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389934/maven-implicit-provided-dependencies-not-shown-in-dependencytree